# MeteorJS on Synology DS214Play (intel architecture)

Tags: meteor, intel, synology

i've replaced my DS212 (on ARM) by a new DS214Play (on Intel).
I tried to install MeteorJs using required command line by any user (admin) :

```
curl http://install.meteor.com | sh
```

Then it tells me that it's installed, but in fact meteor is not callable :

```
sh: meteor: not found
```

After install i get those files:

```
/volume1/homes/admin/.meteor/*
/usr/local/bin/meteor
```

[edit]
trying to install throught https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor and i get the following errors (make has been installed throught ipkg) :

```
Node.js configure error: No acceptable C compiler found!

    Please make sure you have a C compiler installed on your system and/or
    consider adjusting the CC environment variable if you installed
    it in a non-standard prefix.

python ./configure
Node.js configure error: No acceptable C compiler found!

    Please make sure you have a C compiler installed on your system and/or
    consider adjusting the CC environment variable if you installed
    it in a non-standard prefix.

python tools/gyp_node.py -f make
gyp: Undefined variable node_tag in /tmp/generate-dev-bundle-IKZIGinD/build/node/node.gyp
make: *** [out/Makefile] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure if your architecture is supported by now with a pre-bundle.

You can try to check if our "universal" bundler will help you.

https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor

P.S.: Make sure to have node, npm and mongo natively installed on your system when using above.

P.P.S.: You also can try to checkout meteor directly from their repos, depends on architecture.

Comment: I'm trying to use your repos. I installed nodejs and mongodb, but with native meteor repo i have some shell error. If it's ok with your repo i'll chek your answer

Comment: Hi Rebolon what is the underlaying distro on your system? Debian or something else? Looks for me like build_essentials are not installed.

Comment: On a synology this is a Linux DiskStaion 3.2.4. I installed make, perl, python throught ipkg package manager, but i have certainly missed something. If i try to install in the standard way, meteor script tells me that everything is ok, but in fact if i launch "meteor" i get /bin/sh: meteor: not found. If i try sh meteor i get sh: can't open meteor. If i try sh /usr/local/bin/meteor i get /usr/local/bin/meteor: exec: line 93: /root/.meteor/meteor: not found

Comment: Hi Rebon for the standard installation, I guess this is quite explainable. If you do normal install then the process will download an pre-bundled and compiled environment stack for meteor depending your system. I think, that in case that the board is Intel the install process will not fail but can not get a pre-bundled archive. So meteor IS NOT INSTALLED. There is a wrapper script called "meteor" but it just looks for the bundle. I am sure that you will have to build meteor from checkout to get a bundle on your environment.

Comment: So follow up with generate-dev-bundle script. It is important that you will have the build-essential on your system like headers and gcc and so on. Take a look at the packet list on debian: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/build-essential

Comment: i tried to install gcc make automake and re-run the generate script but it still says that i need a C Compiler.
I set CC with /root/gcc value but it fails also. No more idea

Comment: Hi, what is happen if you call:
    "which gcc"
on console? Are the tools and libs in your search pathes? /root/gcc isn't a standard so how do have installed gcc and the other packages? I am sory but have not yet get in touch with a ds214

Comment: On the Synology i installed gcc with ipkg. The DS214 is like other DS21x except that the processor is an intel Atom instead of an ARM Marwell. NodeJs and Mongo are installed so i'm going to demeteorize an app and see if it works "as is".